# How can I access the Kubernetes service from the Internet?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, ip, minikube

I installed the Kubernetes (minikube) cluster on Linux Mint. Then I deploy the demo [Example: Deploying WordPress and MySQL with Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress
labels:
  app: wordpress
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      nodePort: 30375
  selector:
    app: wordpress
    tier: frontend
  type: NodePort
  externalIPs:
    - 178.54.220.175
    - 192.168.1.10
```

How to access the Kubernetes service from the Internet if the external ip 178.54.220.175 is only in the router, host ip with Linux 192.168.1.10 and ip Kubernetes 192.168.99.100:30375.

How to associate these ip addresses with 178.54.220.175 -> 192.168.1.10 -> 192.168.99.100:30375

Comment: In general and the same in the example you brought with mysql external ips are given when the service type is load balancer.

Comment: I can remove ExternalIPs. But this does not change the situation.

Comment: You can either change the Type to load balancer or use the node port you exposed http://<nodeip>:<nodeport>

Comment: It works as you say. I want to enter a dedicated external IP and get on my Kubernetes service.

Comment: You can make a specific url by creating an ingress

Comment: Show me how to do this.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a minikube, this feature is disabled.

When using VirtualBox as hypervisor, you can also use the VirtualBox NAT port forwarding feature to allow access to services exposed through NodePorts from outside.

Something like this (limited range, exposing the entire default NodePort range of 30000-32767 takes forever...):

```
for port in {30000..30100}; do VBoxManage controlvm minikube natpf1 "NodePort$port,tcp,,$port,,$port"; done
```

You can combine that with a reverse SSH tunnel to a VPS so anyone can have temporary access from the public internet:

```
R_ARGS=$(for port in {30000..30100}; do echo -n "-R $port:localhost:$port "; done)
```

---

```
autossh -M 0 -q -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=5 -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 user@examplevps.com -N $R_ARGS
```

To delete the VirtualBox port forward rules:

```
for port in {30000..30100}; do VBoxManage controlvm minikube natpf1 delete "NodePort$port"; done
```

The SSH forward method is easier though, and hypervisor agnostic I suppose, so thanks for that!

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/877

https://cwienczek.com/reaching-minikube-from-your-machines-public-ip-aka-network-bridge/